# xen hotplug can't add vif to eth0: operation not supported

Tags: xen

I am new to xen and I am trying to get a domU running but I am having problems with it. I think my network card might not support bridging which is bizarre.

This is the error I get when trying to create the domU

```
[root@hyrba ~]# xm create sardis.secusrvr.com.cfg
Using config file "/etc/xen/sardis.secusrvr.com.cfg".
Error: Device 0 (vif) could not be connected. Hotplug scripts not working.
```

All the xen kernel modules are loaded...

```
xen_pciback            52948  0 
xen_gntalloc            6807  0 
xen_acpi_processor      5390  1 
xen_netback            27155  0 [permanent]
xen_blkback            21827  0 [permanent]
xen_gntdev             10849  1 
xen_evtchn              5215  1 
xenfs                   3326  1 
xen_privcmd             4854  16 xenfs
```

I get this error in /var/log/xen/xen-hotplug.log

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
can't add vif2.0 to bridge eth0: Operation not supported
can't add vif2.0-emu to bridge eth0: Operation not supported
```

Comment: eth0 is a very unusual name for a bridge. It is normally br0 or something like that. eth0 or peth0 should then be member of that bridge. [**This** question on UL](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86056/11083) might help you to understand the principle of bridging.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been some time since this question was asked, but for benefit of others will post the solution that helped me.

Had similar error on Oracle OVM 2, was not able to start VM:

```
# tail /var/log/xen/xen-hotplug.log 
...
can't add vif128.0 to bridge eth0: Operation not supported
...
```

**Problem**: biding to incorrect interface.

**Solution**: editing `vm.cfg` and changing the **vif=** parameter node "bridge" from `eth0` to **xenbr0** the VM started:

#### Before

```
# cat vm.cfg | grep '^vif'
vif = ['bridge=eth0,mac=00:16:3E:01:59:04,type=ioemu']
```

#### After

```
# cat vm.cfg | grep '^vif'
vif = ['bridge=xenbr0,mac=00:16:3E:01:59:04,type=ioemu']
```